# Bookshelf.js: Saving or Updating many-to-many relationships

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, orm, bookshelf.js

Both the `attach` and `updatePivot` methods for Collections in Bookshelf.js seem to act on many-to-many relationships, but neither of these seem to save or update (upsert) many-to-many relationship items.  When running `attach` I would like to update the records if they already exist or save them if they don't.  Unfortunately, `attach` always adds the records regardless if the relationship already exists, which leads to duplicate entries.  If I use `updatePivot`, it seems to correctly update the records, but only if they exist.  If I'm saving for the first time and I use `updatePivot`, it throws an error.  I'd like to find out if there is a method or strategy that exists to correctly upsert many-to-many relationships in Bookshelf.js.  Here is an example code snippet to give you an idea of what I've tried.

```
qq.save().tap(q => q.choice_responses().attach(cleanQuestions[qq.id]));
qq.save().tap(q => q.choice_responses().updatePivot(cleanQuestions[qq.id]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `detach()` [method](https://bookshelfjs.org/api.html#Collection-instance-detach) without any arguments to remove all the relationships first, then attach them again.